# GwtQuery best practice

Tags: gwt, gwtquery, gquery

What is the best way to build a large app (really large) with GwtQuery

- use it with Gwt Mvp i.e. Activities / places ?
- use it with Mvp4G or Gwtp like framework ?
- use it alone ?

Any pointers shall be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gQuery is not a framework, just a utility library which adds sugar syntax to Gwt java, so as you can deal with DOM using the popular jQuery API. It also adds some utilities like Promises, Easy Ajax, Json and Xml data binding etc.

Said that, the best practices for gwtquery could be:

1. Chose the final architecture in GWT you are happier with. You can use GWT plain widgets, or GWT MVP, GWTP, MGWT, GXT, Vaadin etc.
2. Use gQuery to write less code for certain tasks

   - If you have to parse JSON or XML don't use gwt but gQuery builders
   - If you have to consume 3 party services or your app does not use rpc nor rf, use gQuery `Ajax` instead of dealing with `RequestBuilder`.
   - If you have very nested asynchronous code use gQuery `Promises` instead.
   - For drag and drop use gquery DnD plugin
   - To quick write something to console just use `console.log` instead of having to configure gwt loggers.
   - To avoid boiler plate of deferred binding per permutation just use `if (Browser.isIE) ...` and take advantage of code removal.
   - To include external JS in your compiled output use `JsniBundler`
   - To consume external JS methods use just `JsUtils` from gQuery
   - To add extra events to widgets or elements use `GQuery.on()`. Even you could replace the `EventBus` to fire custom events with data (better performance btw).
   - etc
3. If you use any MVP pattern, use gQuery DOM manipulation in View implementations, and Ajax,  Promises and Json parsing in your presenters so that you can test your code in JVM
4. To enhance existing gwt widgets, don't extend them but modify their DOM structure with gQuery in your views, so as you can:

   - change and style the inner HTML
   - add missing behaviour adding new events etc.
   - overcome the Widget API limitation
5. To create new Gwt widgets it could be much easier to do write gQuery plugin and optionally offer a Gwt API for non gwtquery users.
6. If your app architecture is simple enough or you only have to deal with DOM and REST use just gwtquery for all: Rest consuming, UI, etc like you would do with jQuery

We (Julien and me) gave an interesting presentation last year in the [GWT.create 2013](http://gwtcreate.com/2013/videos/) conferences. You have the [interactive slides](http://slides.gquery.org/gwtcreate/gwtcreate.html) or its [static version](http://es.slideshare.net/dodotis), and I am giving a presentation speaking about gQuery and its best practices on the [GWT.create 2015](http://gwtcreate.com/#agenda-us_room3_event8)

Comment: When you bind event handler on a Widget, don't forget to do that when the widget is already attached to the DOM:

    myWidget.addAttachHandler(new Handler() {
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            if (event.isAttached()) {
                $(myWidget).on("click", new Function() {
                   ...
                });
            } else {
                $(myWidget).off("click");
            }
        }
    });

Comment: Awesome.. I have done a few ui snippets with gquery and I can swear by the performance. Combined with super dev mode it plugs a big hole in the gwt eco system.

Comment: I am also looking forward to a more matured JsQuery. That would save lives of java web developers :)

Comment: On top the slides are simply awesome. Though I won't make it to GWT.create unfortunately I will look forward to the videos. And plan to write a bunch of plugins(hopefully) that I will share for sure. Thanks a ton

Comment: I'm glad that you enjoy gQuery. Yes, please share those plugins we will mention them in our site or help you with anything you need.